# Electron not executing my JS

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have my electron window, it loads all right except that the JS is not run. I can't find out why. Here is my code:

```
...
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="./assets/default.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'unsafe-inline';">
  <script>
    (function() {
      "use_strict";
      console.log('lul'); // Doesn't log 'lul'
      var jq = require("./assets/jquery.min.js");
    });
  </script>
</head>
...
```

This has been frustrating my for a while. I get no errors in the console, and no log. I am new to electron.

Comment: You aren’t calling the function. That’s not how an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your function is declared but never invoked. Try:

```
(function() {
  "use_strict";
  console.log('lul'); // Doesn't log 'lul'
  var jq = require("./assets/jquery.min.js");
}());
```

The `()` at the end makes it an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

As a side note, I believe the `require` is going to throw an error if you run it in a browser without converting it with babel or some other transpiler.

Comment: Thanks for the bit of info. This is the correct answer thanks. And `require` would throw an error in a browser but I am using Electron with Node Scripts enabled.